# Can I use Filemaker with Command Line like SQL as a User (not Admin)?

Tags: command-line, terminal, filemaker

I'm just a user of a Filemaker Database. I don't know if it's the design of the database of the FM app itself, it's just VERY VERY slow... Such a waste of time!

I wonder can I use Filemaker in command lines like how I do for SQL? (as a user without admin privileges)

I'm using OSX.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to access the raw data using SQL with ODBC, but that required someone with full access to the database to set it up and give your account access. Additional options include PHP and XML, which requires setup on FileMaker Server.

In general, FileMaker is not slow, but you may suffer from a poor design, network issues, server hardware issues, etc. that may affect the performance.
Indexing is the key to speed, there may be operations performed on unindexed fields over the network which will slow things down dramatically on large datasets.